# How to make script to add some text to newly created files

Tags: scripts

Is it possible to make some script to add some text to newly created files?

For example, when i make a Virtual Machine there will be a new file `101.conf`. If I make another virtual machine then will be `102.conf`, 103, 104, `105.conf` etc and I must edit each file to write some command or settings in it.

I don't know if it is possible to make a script to check if new files arrived and add some settings automatically?

Comment: Hi! welcome to AU! Which settings(type)? does that settings are saved in another file? and how settings should be add to the newly created files(the place)?

Comment: Do yo want all files to contain exactly the same thing (and all take on the same changes)? If so link them together. Assuming 101.conf is your master, try `rm 102.conf; ln 101.conf 102.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add the same settings to the end of any file, and you can have comments in the file (say started with a #) you could try something like this:

```
additions='# standard additions
[ ... whatever you wanted to add]'

for file in *.conf; do
    grep -q "# standard additions" "$file" ||
    echo "$additions" >>"$file"
done
```